# Which probability is less likely

Tags: probability, notation

If two events ($A$ and $B$) have a probability of occurring ($p(A) = 13.2 \times 10^{-4}$) and ($p(B)= 10.01 \times 10^{-4}$) which one is more likely to occur?

It's just been too long since I have had to convert scientific notation.

Thanks.

Here's a link to the a graph from the paper I'm trying to make sense of (from whence these two figures arise).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtLQQ.jpg

Comment: $13.2\cdot 10^{-4}  = 0.001320 > 0.001001 = 10.01\cdot 10^{-4}$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. In this particular case you can forget about the scientific notation as they both have the same order ($10^{-4}$). So you have that

`13.2 * (sth) > 10.01 * (the same sth)`

equivalent to (as is not negative) :

`13.2  > 10.01`

so A is more likely to occur that B

(remember though here we are analyzing the inequation, as probabilities cannot be bigger that 1)